# O que é DOM Parser?

Tags: terminologia, dom, parser

Lendo sobre expressão regular vi um termo recorrente, DOM parser, e me surgiram as dúvidas:

1. O que é DOM Parser?
2. Como funciona?
3. Toda linguagem tem?

Comment: Ótima pergunta, sempre quis entender o parse do DOM de uma forma mais abrangente, tanto para documentos HTML ou outra estrutura :D ! [Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40852/o-que-%C3%A9-dom-render-tree-e-node) tem algo relacionado.

Comment: Relacionado http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40852/101

Comment: A resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## *Parser*

Vamos começar pelo *parser*. Ele é um algoritmo que faz análise sintática de um texto identificando suas partes (*tokens*) e verificando se tudo está construído conforme determina uma gramática especificada (provavelmente em [BNF](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178720/101)). Neste uso específico ele faz a análise de um documento XML, HTML, etc. e gera um DOM para a aplicação usar.

Ele vai fazendo a análise elemento por elemento do texto e cria a estrutura em árvore. Isso é explicado um pouco melhor em uma [pergunta sobre funcionamento de um compilador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104814/101).

## DOM

O [Document Object Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) é um grande objeto hierárquico com diversos elementos formando uma árvore.

É muito comum encontrarmos o DOM associados à linguagens XML e assemelhados. É possível que alguns compiladores de linguagens de programação gerem um DOM do código para seu próprio uso, e até mesmo disponibilize-o para a aplicação usar em tempo de execução. C# faz isso, mas hoje tem soluções melhores.

Não gosto muito do nome porque remete a fazer o *parsing* do DOM e na verdade o DOM é o resultado que ele gera.

> Toda linguagem tem?

Como o DOM parser é um software com diversos componentes de função específica não é que linguagens vão ter ou não, é uma questão de ter uma biblioteca com essa função disponível para aquela linguagem. Se a linguagem manipula XML, HTML ou algo assim é praticamente certo que exista alguma coisa pronta na biblioteca padrão da linguagem. A qualidade e extensão de cada um pode variar.

Se a "linguagem" não tiver sempre é possível usar uma biblioteca de terceiros.

Não confundir o DOM com o próprio texto que gerar esse modelo. Um HTML não é o DOM, mas é normal ter uma relação direta entre eles. Você pode manipular o DOM sem manipular o HTML. Ou XML, ou JSON (menos comum), SVG, etc. O JavaScript manipula o DOM, não o HTML diretamente.

O *parser* entrega uma estrutura parcial ou integral em forma de árvore para que o código consumidor possa fazer o que deseja. Em geral a biblioteca do *parser* permite acessar os membros do DOM de forma fácil e até mesmo manipulá-lo.

Algumas linguagens, como é o caso do JavaScript, por característica específica, pode ter acesso ao DOM de forma direta, já que o DOM acaba sendo incorporado aos identificadores do código.

Está sendo criada uma [especificação formal](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/WD-DOM-Parsing-20160517/) de como ele deve funcionar.

Veja mais em [O que é parse, e como funciona o parse do DOM no HTML5?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/99632/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).