# Abrir executável pela aplicação web

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho um código que abre um software externo a minha aplicação.

```
 <script>
    function run(file) {
      var ws;
      ws = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
      ws.run(file);
    }
</script>
```

Só que o software externo abre no computador como normalmente, eu quero fazer este software abrir dentro na página web em html.

Como eu poderia fixar este software na página, é possível faze isso?

Comment: Não tenho certeza, mas acho que você precisa de um back-end pra poder fazer a execução do script.

Comment: este código que coloquei acima já está funcionando, o software está sendo aberto normalmente, agora eu preciso fixar ele na página. Você acha que preciso de um back-end para isto?

Comment: Você quer fazer um .exe abrir dentro de um html?

Comment: isso! é possível?

Comment: Não entendi bem, mas vocÊ quer abrir no browser do usuário um executável que está no servidor?

Comment: Isso mesmo Ricardo.

Comment: Então, @Lorena, você quer abrir no lado do cliente um executável que está no servidor. Eu acho que só com back end mesmo... não consigo pensar numa solução dessa sem back end.

Comment: você vai precisar de uma linguagem que é executada do lado do servidor, exemplo PHP

Comment: Sim @MarllonNasser isso já está fazendo, o que eu preciso agora é fazer como se o software externo e minha aplicação fossem uma coisa só, ou seja, fazer o software rodar dentro da aplicação.

Comment: Então Lorena, seu script funciona se acessado diretamente, agora voce precisa de uma linguagem Web para executar esse script e printar para o usuário o resultado do script

Comment: Seria bom vc dar mais detalhes, o que exatamente esse script faz, qual conteúdo final precisa ser exibido para o usuário ,etc...

Comment: O conteúdo final é software executado na tela para o usuário mexer, software externo integrado com a página web, como se os dois fossem a mesma coisa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se eu entendi corretamente, você que abrir um programa que está alojado em uma máquina no browser.

No caso da execução na máquina ele tem um ambiente propício para tal, já o browser comum não oferece, por exemplo acesso a memória, o que pode fazer é desenvolver um browser que propicie a execução desse programa, o que na verdade se for apenas para esse fim, num vale a pena.

Outra situação é você transformar o teu código em algo que o browser possa utilizar.

Comment: Muito obrigada pela resposta @MagicHat o que seria um código que o browser possa utilizar? O código que você diz seria o do software externo?

Comment: O browser tem um [Parser](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/179714/o-que-%C3%A9-dom-parser#179747) , tudo que "parsar". vai pra tela...

Comment: Mas tudo depende da finalidade, o que tem na sua aplicação dá para rodar no browser ou ela vai precisar se utilizar do SO ?

Comment: da pra rodar no browser

Comment: Ou você faz em uma linguagem direto para o browser ou você faz pelo servidor usando [CGI](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/93308/o-que-%C3%A9-cgi-e-qual-%C3%A9-sua-finalidade/132360#132360)

Comment: pelo que entendo então é usando CGI