# Como é desenvolvida uma linguagem de programação?

Tags: característica-linguagem, independente-de-linguagem, design-de-linguagem

Como uma linguagem de programação é criada?

Em termos gerais, por onde e como funciona a validação das funcionalidades da nova linguagem?

Por exemplo, temos a linguagem C++, ela é complexa e tem bastante conteúdo e utilização, mas como chegou até aqui? Como se iniciou, como foi criada? Estou usando o C++ só como um exemplo, a pergunta é mais geral.

Não quero saber sobre o que é uma linguagem de programação que já tem pergunta sobre isto. Não quero saber sobre como funciona um compilador e a diferença dele para a linguagem, isto já foi perguntado antes.

Comment: Vc pode começar [por aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101691/o-que-%C3%A9-linguagem-de-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ide-e-compilador).

Comment: [O que é analise léxica?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/113578/91) e [O que é linguagem de programação, IDE e compilador?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/91)

Comment: Poderia explicar o que é "validação de funções"? Uma linguagem nova geralmente surge pela insatisfação dos programadores com as atuais, qualquer um pode criar uma nova linguagem desde uma pessoa até uma empresa, a adição/remoção de funcionalidades pode(geralmente) é feita por um comite que vota(contra ou a favor) nessas atualizações/especificações.

Comment: a pergunta não foi duplicada, não tem relação, até tem, porém não estou perguntando o que é e sim como é.

Comment: Não sei se eu entendi o ponto principal da sua pergunta. Vc não quer saber nada específico do C++, mas sim genérico? A sua intenção é saber o histórico das linguagens de programação e por que as decisões que foram tomadas (seja qual forem) foram tomadas? Está confuso, e eu tendo a votar como não claro. Mas mesmo que for isso, ai fica *só* amplo demais.

Comment: @VictorGomes eu editei a pergunta para tentar deixá-la mais adequada e clara baseado no que eu entendi. Veja se não mudei sua intenção original. Pode mudar se achou que está ruim, ou pode falar alguma coisa que acha que está ruim.

Comment: A pergunta é simples, como é o processo, como funciona o desenvolvimento de uma linguagem, não quero nada de complexo, apenas uma dúvida que tem um conteúdo vago na internet. Resumo do resumo é como é criada uma linguagem, ela tem que ter um inicio certo? Como ela começa. (Quando digo ela, digo qualquer linguagem de programação, sem especificar ou referenciar nenhuma, em modo geral, como é criado uma linguagem de programação) Bom, espero que tenha ajudado para entender e é uma pena estarem dando down vote e 1 voto para fechar a pergunta.

Comment: Esta pergunta está a ser discutida no meta: [Pergunta fechada mas continua aberta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5008/7210)

Comment: @JorgeB. na verdade, não :) Está sendo discutido um *bug* ou algo assim, a pergunta está claro que não é duplicata e nem me parece ser ampla, o que não está em discussão lá.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

## O início

É igual fazer qualquer software.

Uma linguagem nova surge da necessidade de resolver algum tipo problema específico ou geral de forma diferente do que se fazia antes. Foi assim quando se criou as primeiras linguagens de baixo nível (vários *Assemblies*) e depois com Fortran - considerada a primeira linguagem de alto nível - e então linguagens que foram usando ou adicionando novos paradigmas e estilos de código, atendendo necessidades que antes não eram contempladas pelas linguagens anteriores.

Claro que é possível criar uma linguagem sem inovar, sem atender uma necessidade não atendida antes. Pode-se criar uma só como exercício ou outro motivo.

Criar uma linguagem de programação é juntar um monte de ideias e regras e formalizar tudo, em maior ou menor grau. Uma linguagem é algo conceitual, é abstrata.

## Filosofia

Obviamente durante a criação da linguagem tem uma série de decisões que deve-se tomar que vão além da gramática ou que vão influenciar a gramática (ver abaixo sobre o que é). Por exemplo:

- que [paradigma(s)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_paradigm) a linguagem adotará
- [modelo de tipagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/101) e de gerenciamento de memória
- critérios de eficiência de execução e tradução do código
- usabilidade, simplicidade, legibilidade, manutibilidade
- confiabilidade, precisão, robustez - o que é proibido (erro), permitido (alerta) e regular
- universalidade, portabilidade, forma de execução
- expressividade, estilo de sintaxe
- extensibilidade
- generalidade (ou o nicho específico)
- ortogonalidade, uniformidade, regularidade, consistência
- facilidade de implementação e ambientação
- como tratará situações específicas (manipulação de erros, facilidades para integração de ferramentas como *debug* ou IDE, por exemplo)

Até mesmo algumas coisas incomuns podem ser decididas e/ou especificadas. Outras, é melhor deixar em aberto, [a linguagem não precisa exigir que tudo seja especificado e deixar que a implementação tenha uma certa liberdade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111284/101).

Por isso antes de começar especificar a gramática costuma-se definir uma "visão", uma filosofia para a linguagem. São poucos itens que vão guiar as decisões, principalmente quando houver conflitos entre uma decisão e outra.

Pense que você está criando um produto, ou mesmo uma empresa. Precisa ter um "norte" para saber onde quer chegar, qual o resultado esperado, o que, em linhas gerais, pode ou não pode fazer quando surgir um obstáculo ou uma oportunidade. Quais são os "valores" da linguagem. [Python tem isso formalmente](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), [C++ também](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) (provavelmente o mais bem definido, e seguido desde que existe, de todas linguagens).

Claro que se for geral demais, no fundo encaixa qualquer coisa. E se não for pra seguir, melhor não fazer. Se fizer e for rígido demais, a linguagem certamente será ruim.

## Gramática

Como é uma linguagem ela precisa de uma [gramática](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar). Ou seja, precisa de um conjunto de regras para uso das palavras (incluso aí como essas são escritas). É comum que essas regras sejam escritas em [BNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) ou alguma variação dessa notação (curiosamente BNF não deixa de ser uma linguagem). Um [exemplo da linguagem C](https://cs.wmich.edu/%7Egupta/teaching/cs4850/sumII06/The%20syntax%20of%20C%20in%20Backus-Naur%20form.htm). [Gramática do JavaScript](http://tomcopeland.blogs.com/EcmaScript.html). Existe uma [pergunta no SO com várias outras](https://stackoverflow.com/q/334479/221800).

Essas regras são [sintáticas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_%28programming_languages%29) e [semânticas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_%28computer_science%29).

Existem alguns softwares que ajudam montar sua gramática, testá-la se tudo se encaixa como devido, e até mesmo [gerar uma base de código para o compilador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2130/101). Exemplos: [YACC/Bison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc), [ANTLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANTLR), [GOLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GOLD_%28parser%29), [Coco/R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coco/R), [Flex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_%28lexical_analyser_generator%29), etc. Eles não fazem milagres. Se não usar um software desses, tem que fazer na mão, como em tudo na computação. Testar sem ajuda é tedioso e indutor de erros no processo.

Durante a criação da gramática é provável que mude muita coisa que se tinha ideia inicial. Algumas coisas não funcionam bem com outras como se costuma imaginar inicialmente. Depende da [ortogonalidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/195461/101).

Sempre vejo questionamentos sobre porque uma linguagem não permite isso ou aquilo. Quem é leigo no assunto acha que criaram a linguagem de um jeito errado. Muitas vezes há uma dificuldade ter tudo na mesma linguagem, as características não se encaixam. Outras apenas não se encaixam no objetivo traçado. E outras são erros mesmo :). Já quem não é programador nem consegue pensar nesse questionamento.

## E depois?

Algumas regras, além da gramática, de como a implementação da linguagem podem ser especificadas e aí todo [compilador/interpretador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77070/101) deve segui-las.

Depois de definir a linguagem, normalmente vem a definição de uma biblioteca padrão que toda implementação deve ter.

Com a [linguagem especificada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language_specification), é possível [escrever um compilador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104814/101) para ela. É a [implementação da linguagem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language_implementation). Aqui ela começa ficar concreta.

Obviamente outras ferramentas para auxiliá-la podem ser úteis, mas não obrigatórias.

Criadores de linguagens de uso geral adoram reescrever o compilador nela própria, assim que possível, serve até como marketing, isto chama-se *bootstrapping*.

## Testes

Com a especificação fica fácil usar [TDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) (nunca vi fazerem :D). Um compilador é um projeto que esta metodologia cai muito bem, mas não obrigatória. Pelo menos [testes de unidade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) devem ser feitos. Os testes devem sempre corresponder à especificação. Em alguns casos onde a especificação não seja formalizada, os testes servem como especificação.

## Informações adicionais

- [Diferença entre a linguagem, compilador e IDE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101)
- [O que é uma linguagem de programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102452/101)
- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language)
- [Linguagem formal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language)
- [Teoria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language_theory)
- [Tutorial](http://compilers.iecc.com/crenshaw/) (é bom em certo aspecto, mas ruim e outros)
- [Artigo de quem tem experiência](http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/so-you-want-to-write-your-own-language/240165488)
- [Mais um tutorial](http://scratch-lang.notimetoplay.org/)
- [Dragon Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321486811) (dá a base, mas hoje costuma-se fazer diferente)
- [Livro referência](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123745144)

## C++

C++ é uma evolução do C. Basicamente toda linguagem é evolução de outras. Ela sempre agrega ou tira características para ter um conjunto de "funções" mais adequado para um determinado objetivo. Ela foi sendo definida por uma pessoa na AT&T, o mesmo local onde a linguagem C foi criada para escrever o Unix.

Seu objetivo era dar mais segurança e ser uma versão orientada a objetos do C. [O Bjarne foi pensando no que precisava adicionar](http://www.stroustrup.com/hopl2.pdf), usando um pouco [Simula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simula) como base de ideias, especificava e ia analisando se as coisas se encaixavam, se algo poderia trazer problemas.

Existe uma [filosofia básica para evolução da linguagem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Design_goals). [Gramática do C++](http://www.nongnu.org/hcb/).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Ótimo que pelo menos 1 pessoa conseguiu entender a pergunta, ótima explicação e um resumo muito bem elaborado, conteúdo interessante, com certeza irei estudar sobre.

Comment: @bigown exemplo da linguagem C...

Comment: @JorgeB. pedi para outras pessoas acessarem e está ok.

Comment: @bigown "An error occurred during a connection to cs.wmich.edu. SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG"

Comment: Ou ocorre por acidente como no caso do PHP. :P