# Quantas Strings são criadas nos códigos abaixo?

Tags: java, string, jvm

Quantas `String`s a JVM cria, de fato, durante o tempo de execução dos trechos de código abaixo?

**1**:

```
String s1 = "s1";
```

**2**:

```
String s2 = new String("s2");
```

**3**:

```
String s3 = "s3";
String s4 = s3 + "s4";
```

**4**:

```
String s5 = "s5";
String s6 = s5 + "-" + "s6";
```

**5**:

```
final String s7 = "s7";
String s8 = s7 + "s8";
```

**6**:

```
final String s9 = "s9";
String s10 = s9 + "-" + "s10";
```

Comment: Agora que eu vi que tem um -1, acho ele bem errado, a pergunta é sensacional.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não é uma resposta completa, mas dá uma ideia.

Compilei a seguinte classe com o javac 1.8.0_111:

```
public class Teste {
    public String x() {
        String s1 = "s1";

        String s2 = new String("s2");

        String s3 = "s3";
        String s4 = s3 + "s4";

        String s5 = "s5";
        String s6 = s5 + "-" + "s6";

        final String s7 = "s7";
        String s8 = s7 + "s8";

        final String s9 = "s9";
        String s10 = s9 + "-" + "s10";

        return s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 + s5 + s6 + s7 + s8 + s9 + s10;
    }
}
```

E descompilei o resultado:

```
/*
 * Decompiled with CFR 0_118.
 */
public class Teste {
    public String x() {
        String string = "s1";
        String string2 = new String("s2");
        String string3 = "s3";
        String string4 = string3 + "s4";
        String string5 = "s5";
        String string6 = string5 + "-s6";
        String string7 = "s7s8";
        String string8 = "s9-s10";
        return string + string2 + string3 + string4 + string5 + string6 + "s7" + string7 + "s9" + string8;
    }
}
```

Usando um outro descompilador:

```
// 
// Decompiled by Procyon v0.5.30
// 

public class Teste
{
    public String x() {
        final String s = "s1";
        final String s2 = new String("s2");
        final String s3 = "s3";
        final String string = s3 + "s4";
        final String s4 = "s5";
        return s + s2 + s3 + string + s4 + (s4 + "-s6") + "s7" + "s7s8" + "s9" + "s9-s10";
    }
}
```

Observe que o compilador foi esperto e já fez algumas das concatenações por si mesmo, e que portanto o resultado nem sempre vai ser óbvio. Entretanto, claramente, ele poderia ser ainda mais esperto do que é.

Tentei fazer uma variante retirando os modificadores `final`, acreditando que não faria diferença. **Para a minha surpresa, o `final` fez diferença sim.** Eis os resultados da descompilação:

```
/*
 * Decompiled with CFR 0_118.
 */
public class Teste2 {
    public String x() {
        String string = "s1";
        String string2 = new String("s2");
        String string3 = "s3";
        String string4 = string3 + "s4";
        String string5 = "s5";
        String string6 = string5 + "-s6";
        String string7 = "s7";
        String string8 = string7 + "s8";
        String string9 = "s9";
        String string10 = string9 + "-s10";
        return string + string2 + string3 + string4 + string5 + string6 + string7 + string8 + string9 + string10;
    }
}
```

```
// 
// Decompiled by Procyon v0.5.30
// 

public class Teste2
{
    public String x() {
        final String s = "s1";
        final String s2 = new String("s2");
        final String s3 = "s3";
        final String string = s3 + "s4";
        final String s4 = "s5";
        final String string2 = s4 + "-s6";
        final String s5 = "s7";
        final String string3 = s5 + "s8";
        final String s6 = "s9";
        return s + s2 + s3 + string + s4 + string2 + s5 + string3 + s6 + (s6 + "-s10");
    }
}
```

Tentei também mais uma variante, colocando `final` em todas as variáveis:

```
/*
 * Decompiled with CFR 0_118.
 */
public class Teste3 {
    public String x() {
        String string = new String("s2");
        return "s1" + string + "s3" + "s3s4" + "s5" + "s5-s6" + "s7" + "s7s8" + "s9" + "s9-s10";
    }
}
```

```
// 
// Decompiled by Procyon v0.5.30
// 

public class Teste3
{
    public String x() {
        return "s1" + new String("s2") + "s3" + "s3s4" + "s5" + "s5-s6" + "s7" + "s7s8" + "s9" + "s9-s10";
    }
}
```

Ou seja, o código com o `final` compila melhor.

Comment: `string8` e  `string9`: foram criadas só as strings concatenadas. Não foram criados os literais e depois a concatenação. Essas duas strings concatenaram literais com variáveis `final`.

Comment: "Não é uma resposta completa" - Essa foi a melhor resposta até agora rsrs. Então, de fato, existe uma certa/considerável diferença entre concatenar strings com variáveis `final`, correto? @bigown

Comment: Eu acho mesmo que essa é a que deu mais informações úteis, só não a vejo como resposta definitiva. @igorventurelli sim, fica claro para **este** compilador. O que não ficou claro pra mim é qual é o papel do descompilador nas otimizações aí. Pra mim foi um resultado mutcho loco :)

Comment: @igorventurelli Resposta editada. Surpreendente.

Comment: @bigown Resposta editada.

Comment: @VictorStafusa se eu fosse fazer o compilador eu tentaria fazer esta otimização. Tem gente que acha que é analisar um pouco além da conta. E aí caímos naquelas velhas perguntas: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2130/101 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2044/101. Muito boa pergunta, pena que o pessoal não deu valor pra ela. Vou ver se faço uns testes com C# depois.

Comment: @bigown De certo. Já estou querendo me empolgar para dar uma olhadinha no código do Javac 9. Inclusive o curioso é que se você compilar, descompilar e compilar de novo o que foi descompilado, neste caso, deve sair um bytecode mais eficiente do que o compilador por si só gera, sendo que o que eu esperaria é o contrário.

Comment: @bigown realmente foi muito instrutivo.

Answer (score 3):

No total, ao longo do código proposto, são criadas 16 Strings, conforme comentários adicionados:

**1**:

```
String s1 = "s1"; // Objeto 1 colocado no Pool
```

**2**:

```
String s2 = new String("s2"); // Objeto 2 e 3, um literal (que vai para o Pool) e outro com o new
```

**3**:

```
String s3 = "s3"; // Objeto 4 colocado na Pool
String s4 = s3 + "s4"; // Objeto 5 não colocado no Pool s4 E Objeto 6 "s4"
```

**4**:

```
String s5 = "s5"; // Objeto 7 colocado no Pool
String s6 = s5 + "-" + "s6"; // Objeto 8 não colocado no Pool s6 e Objeto 9 ("-") colocado no Pool e Objeto 10 "s6"
```

**5**:

```
final String s7 = "s7"; // Objeto 11 colocado no Pool
String s8 = s7 + "s8"; // Objeto 12 não colocado no Pool e Objeto 13 "s8"
```

**6**:

```
final String s9 = "s9"; // Objeto 14 colocado no Pool
String s10 = s9 + "-" + "s10"; // Objeto 15 não colocado no Pool (reutiliza Objeto 9 do pool) e Objeto 16 "s10"
```

**Pool de Strings**

O Java possui um pool de objetos do tipo String. Antes de criar uma
nova String, primeiro ele verifica neste pool se uma String com o mesmo
conteúdo já existe; Neste caso, ele a reutiliza, evitando criar dois objetos exatamente iguais na memória.

É importante observar que o Java apenas coloca no pool as Strings criadas usando literais. Strings criadas com o operador `new` não são colocadas no pool automaticamente.
Outro ponto importante é que as String resultantes de concatenações de literais também são colocadas no pool. Mas isso somente ocorre quando há literais em ambos os lados da concatenação. Se algum dos objetos não for um literal, o resultado será um novo objeto, fora do pool.

Comment: `String s4 = s3 + "s4";` (partindo do princípio que temos `s3` declarada com algum literal), quantas Strings são criadas nesse ponto?

Comment: Pensando melhor, acredito que 2: "s4" e o resultado da concatenação.

Comment: Exato. E além disso, existe um tratamento especial para concatenações com `final`

Comment: Você mesmo pode colocar uma resposta!

Comment: Sim! Estou procurando a fonte onde encontrei isso para ter certeza.

Comment: Não vi nada a respeito. Não tá confundindo com static?

Answer (score 3):

Vou dar uma resposta alternativa porque ou a pergunta é capciosa, ou ela foi mal formulada.

A pergunta fala de criação em tempo de execução. Então não conta as que já foram criadas em tempo de compilação, certo?

Depende da implementação da JVM usada e do compilador Java. Pode haver otimizações ou não em alguns casos. Outros a otimização certamente não é possível, ou só é possível se feita de forma agressiva.

A especificação da linguagem não determina exatamente como o *runtime* deve proceder em vários desses casos.

A nossa pergunta aqui tem a *tag* Java, mas no texto não fala sobre Java, só sobre JVM. Pela sintaxe é improvável que possa ser outra linguagem, mas poderia, o que poderia acontecer outra coisa.

Comment: Sim, _runtime_ ! Coloquei diversas formas de criação para chegar ao ponto do `final`: Existe algum artefato que, ao concatenar um literal com uma variável `final` (String), faz com que sejam criadas menos Strings do que concatenar um literal com uma variável não `final`, correto?

Comment: Então, pode ser que sim, mas não obrigatoriamente. Se quer saber se é possível, sim, é. Se faz de fato, depende.

Comment: Ok, mas depende do que? Vi no SO gringo uma explicação superficial sobre isso há tempos, mas não consigo encontrá-la novamente.

Comment: Depende do compilador e do *runtime*. Eles tem certa liberdade de criar como acharem melhor. Tem algumas coisas na especificação que são obrigatórias, outras não.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro, o compilador já vai criar as `String`s `"s1"`, `"s2"`, `"s3"`, `"s4"`, `"s5"`, `"-s6"`, `"s7"`, `"s8"`, `"s9"` e `"-s10"` e estas estarão presentes no bytecode gerado e no pool de `String`s durante a execução. O compilador é esperto o suficiente para transformar `"-" + "s6"` em `"-s6"` e `"-" + "s10"` em `"-s10"` (ao menos o javac 1.8.0_111 é).

Assim sendo, já começamos com essas 10 `String`s.

```
// 1. Apenas aponta para uma String já existente no pool.
String s1 = "s1";

// 2. Cria uma nova String: "s2".
String s2 = new String("s2");

// 3a. Apenas aponta para uma String já existente.
String s3 = "s3";

// 3b. Cria uma nova String: s4 = "s3s4"
String s4 = s3 + "s4";

// 4a. Apenas aponta para uma String já existente.
String s5 = "s5";

// 4b. Cria uma nova String: s5 = "s5-s6"
String s6 = s5 + "-" + "s6";

// 5a. Apenas aponta para uma String já existente.
final String s7 = "s7";

// 5b. Cria uma nova String: s8 = "s7s8"
String s8 = s7 + "s8";

// 6a. Apenas aponta para uma String já existente.
final String s9 = "s9";

// 6b. Cria uma nova String: s10 = "s9-s10"
String s10 = s9 + "-" + "s10";
```

Além das 10 `String`s presentes originalmente que estavam no bytecode, foram criadas mais 5 `String`s nos passos 2, 3b, 4b, 5b e 6b.

Comment: Sim. Mas chega ao mesmo ponto que estou discutindo com o @bigown. Quando concatenamos uma string literal com uma variável `final` (também String), o comportamento é (ou pode ser) diferente. É isso o que quero entender.

Comment: @igorventurelli O `final` não tem efeito nenhum na execução, é uma coisa que está inteiramente em tempo de compilação. Neste exemplo, o `final` é completamente desnecessário e sem efeito. Faria diferença se após tudo isso você tentasse fazer um `s9 = "x";`, pois daí daria erro de compilação por causa do `final`. O `final` quer dizer que você só pode atribuir a variável uma única vez.

Comment: Sim.. Compreendo isso, mas parece que não é bem assim. Há tempos vi no SO gringo uma resposta/comentário inferindo o comportamento especial do `final` nesse contexto. Vou procurar novamente e posto aqui. Se não encontrar encerro o tópico.

Comment: @VictorStafusa o que deixa margem para haver otimização. Eu duvido que faça, mas é possível.

Comment: @bigown Veja a minha outra resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/185771/132

Comment: @VictorStafusa o mais curioso é o descompilador otimizar :D Agora eu não confio no resultado. Não sei o quanto foi otimização do compilador e o quanto foi do descompilador. Claro que o segundo tem otimizações do descompilador, no primeiro, sei lá quem otimizou isso, pode ser um *mix* dos 2.